# WP_Query paginate with one term per page?

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy

We have a site with an online newsletter/magazine using a custom post type (newsletter).

What we're trying to do is display the articles by 'Issue' (a custom taxonomy called 'issue'), so that all of the current issue (let's say its called 'OCT2019') show up as posts on the main page, then we want previous/next buttons to scroll between the issues. So on the main page there should be a 'previous' button that would then go to the previous issue (SEPT2019).

Is there a way to set up the wp_query to paginate based on taxonomy term.

What I can figure out is we need the query to sort posts in order of when the taxonomy term was created (not sure if that's possible), so when the editor adds a new tax term (like 'NOV2019'), it will show up first.

Then the query needs to paginate based on each tax term in order of creation date....

Lots of problems here I think, but I have to ask anyway. :)

Has anyone had to do this before? Anything close to similar?

Comment: Reasonably speaking it seems you could sort posts (not taxonomy) by date. Use a custom query and set `posts_per_page` to `1` and then order the posts by date DESC.  I don't see a reason to make it more complex.

Comment: @rudtek Thanks for the comment! Perhaps I didn't explain it well enough. For each 'Issue' we'll have 5-10 articles that we'll be posting. Problem is there is no set standard number (if we had 5 posts each time, that'd be easier).